# If command in LaTex

Tags: conditionals, parts

I am writing a project for a course and I want to make each Part to have a different color image on the side. But to do this I have to make a loop (that's what I think) to recognize the Part and and make the corresponding programming. I found this online, but it doesn't return me anything

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\PartRecognizer}[1]
  {
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{Part 1}{}
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{Part 2}{}
  }
\PartRecognizer{\thepart}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Presumably `\thepart` is 0 right now because your document doesn't have any `\part{}`s yet.

Comment: No even when i put in in a part doesn't show nothing

Comment: I found it :/ how stupit.... The part counts I,II,III,IV... and not 1,2,3 :P

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The default `\part`s enumeration in [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) is set using `\Roman{part}`. That is,

```
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
```

However, it's better to not test against the *representation* of the counter, but against the counter itself. To that end, we'll condition on what `\value{part}` looks like.

Finally, since your macro seems solely dedicated to condition on the part, its seems superfluous to pass the part number as an argument.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\PartRecognizer}{%
  Part
  \ifcase\value{part}%
      0%
  \or 1%
  \or 2%
  \else ?%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\part{First part}

\PartRecognizer

\end{document}
```

Note that the part counter is incremented when you call `\part`. So, like *most* counters, its starts with a default of 0.

I've used a "case-like" conditioning above, as you'll step the part counter in single increments, possibly starting from 0 - something that `\ifcase` works well with.

Answer (score 2):

The `\equal` test in `\ifthenelse` compares strings, but you want to compare *numbers*. So

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\PartRecognizer}{%
   \ifthenelse{\value{part}=1}{Part 1}{}%
   \ifthenelse{\value{part}=2}{Part 2}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\PartRecognizer

\end{document}
```

Please, note the `%` comment characters that avoid unwanted spurious space in the output.

This works, but has several defects, because you can't use it for something like

```
\newcommand{\PartRecognizer}{%
   \ifthenelse{\value{part}=1}{duck}{}%
   \ifthenelse{\value{part}=2}{cookiemonster}{}%
}
```

and then

```
\includegraphics{\PartRecognizer}
```

in the place where you want the graphics. This would require more awkward code.

Here's an easier implementation, where adding image names is straightforward. The first part of the code is meant to add the image to the part starting page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox,xparse}

\makeatletter
\preto\@endpart{%
  \vfil
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=.5\textheight]{\partimage}
  \end{center}
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\partimage}{}
 {
  \int_case:nn { \value{part} }
   {
    {1}{duck}
    {2}{cookiemonster}
    % add here file names for the following parts
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\part{Ducks}

\part{Monsters}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>Source for the Cookie Monster's picture: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2428961/Want-cookie-Amazing-picture-underwater-animal-looks-like-Sesame-Street.html</sub>

Comment: ooh cookies! `:)`